# How to check if a particular item exists in a sql table using c# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i want to check if a CNIC no. tat user has entered do not exist in my table then i do not want him to proceed with registration process ...

Here is the code, **A part of which**   is not working .. where am i wrong?

```
con.Open();
        string cmdStr = "Select count(*) from Registration where UserName='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
        string cmdCnic = "Select count(*) from List_CNIC where CNIC='" + TextBoxCNIC.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand userExist=new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
        SqlCommand cnicExist=new SqlCommand(cmdCnic,con);
        int temp=Convert.ToInt32(userExist.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        int tempCnic = Convert.ToInt32(cnicExist.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        con.Close();
        if (temp==1)
        {
            Session["name1"] = TextBoxFN.Text;
            Session["UserName"] = TextBoxUN.Text;
            Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
        } 
       if (!(tempCnic==1))
        {
            Session["nameFull"] = TextBoxFN.Text;
            Session["CNIC"] = TextBoxCNIC.Text;
            Response.Redirect("Error_InvalidCNIC.aspx");

        }
```

The part of the code where i am checking that user name exists or not is working fine, but the check for **tempCnic**. It is automatically redirecting to the page **Error_InvalidCNIC.aspx** even when user has not entered anything.

Whats wrong with the code???

Comment: BTW: You have a SQL Injection vulnerability in that code. This web site could be easily hacked.

Comment: Have you tried actually running the query Select count(*) from List_CNIC where CNIC='' in SSMS to see if it returns what you think it will?

Comment: Or running the code through a debugger and checking what is the return value of **tempCnic**

Answer (score 3):

I would create a Stored Procedure that returns different codes based on insert success, and execute this from your C# code.

```
CREATE PROC RegisterUser
    @UserName nvarchar(255),
    @CNIC nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  Registration WHERE UserName = @UserName)
    BEGIN
        RETURN -1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM List_CNIC WHERE CNIC = @CNIC)
        BEGIN
            RETURN -2
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            --Insert into relevant tables, ideally wrapped in a TRANSACTION with try/catch
            RETURN 1
        END
    END
END
```

I'd then drag this stored procedure onto a LINQ to SQL datacontext, and execute it like this:

```
var db = new DataContextDataClasses();
var result = db.RegisterUser(userName,CNIC);

switch (result) {
    case 1:
         //success
         break;
    case -1:
         //user exists
         break;
    case -2:
         //CNIC exists
         break
    default:
         throw new Exception("Unknown error occurred");
}
```

but you could obviously call this through ADO.NET too...

Comment: Why COUNT instead of IF EXISTS?

Comment: There can be, since COUNT() will have to perform a complete scan, while EXISTS() will return after the first match. Probably not an issue with the username, since if that is unique or a PK that is going to be a pretty efficient scan, but we have no idea what the other table looks like. Since EXISTS *can be no worse* it is what I always use.

Comment: Yep, makes sense.  I see that EXISTS would be better in this instance... have updated to show this (although doesn't look like this solution will be used).

Comment: you don't know that. The OP hasn't decided which solution they will use (if any). Input that you have even if it doesn't help the OP may help other readers today and in the future. So don't feel like your information is wasteful. I upvoted it once you switched to EXISTS. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand i m just wondering that y it is automatically redirecting to the page Error_InvalidCNIC.aspx when user have not even entered any thing in CNIC text box .. thats wat i m looking for ... the CNIC is a 13 digit number which have been saved as varchar(50) type.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the issue. If the user hasn't entered anything then

`Select count(*) from List_CNIC where CNIC=''` should set tempCnic=0

(unless there is a row where CNIC is an empty string)

This block is getting triggered (as you say)

```
if (!(tempCnic==1))
        {
            Session["nameFull"] = TextBoxFN.Text;
            Session["CNIC"] = TextBoxCNIC.Text;
            Response.Redirect("Error_InvalidCNIC.aspx");
    }
```

because !(0==1) yields true.

It is doing exactly what you asked it to do

BTW: It would be easier to read if you wrote this check as `(tempCnic!=1)`

Comment: look ... on click on the link "CLICK HERE TO REGISTER",registration form should be open and it is this form where user will enter user name and cnic, when i performed only Username check that if it already exists in database of registered voters redirect him to an Error page ... i extended the code **BUT this time i wanted that if user enters a CNIC that is NOT already stored in database then he is not eligible to get himself registered to this particular site** this is the reason that when checkd userName used if(temp==1) and for CNIC used if(tempCnic!=1),cox they wer 2 opposite situations

Comment: prob is that on click on "CLICK HERE TO REGISTER" .. registration form is not opening at all and it is redirecting my page to Error_InvalidCNIC.aspx..

Comment: You need to include all the code that is relevant to your question and be more specific about what you are looking for. I am responding to "It is automatically redirecting to the page Error_InvalidCNIC.aspx even when user has not entered anything."

Comment: i m just wondering that y it is automatically redirecting to the page Error_InvalidCNIC.aspx .. thats wat i m looking for ... the CNIC is a 13 digit number which have been saved as varchar(50) type.

Answer (score -4):

I'm into Entity Framework so it may not be your answer but.... you may be interested

```
var stuff = List_CNIC.Where(p => p.CNIC == TextBoxCNIC.Text);
if(stuff.Count() == 1) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask how to rewrite the query in LINQ of EF.